# Symfony4 Kernel doesn't find autoloaded classes

Tags: symfony4, autoload

I have a separate structure for copied libs:

```
bundles/lightsaml/lightsaml/src
bundles/lightsaml/sp-bundle/src
bundles/lightsaml/symfony-bridge/src
bundles/mdanter/ecc/src
bundles/robrichards/xmlseclibs/src
```

And in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "LightSaml\\SymfonyBridgeBundle\\": "bundles/lightsaml/symfony-bridge/src",
        "LightSaml\\SpBundle\\": "bundles/lightsaml/sp-bundle/src",
        "LightSaml\\": "bundles/lightsaml/lightsaml/src",
        "Mdanter\\": "bundles/mdanter/ecc/src",
        "RobRichards\\": "bundles/robrichards/xmlseclibs/src"
    }
},
```

Also tried this variant of `composer.json`:

```
        "LightSaml\\": [
            "bundles/lightsaml/symfony-bridge/src",
            "bundles/lightsaml/lightsaml/src",
            "bundles/lightsaml/sp-bundle/src"
        ],
```

In `config/bundles.php`:

```
LightSaml\SymfonyBridgeBundle\LightSamlSymfonyBridgeBundle::class => ['all' => true],
LightSaml\SpBundle\LightSamlSpBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
***ClassNotFoundException***

Attempted to load class "LightSamlSymfonyBridgeBundle" from namespace "LightSaml\SymfonyBridgeBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "LightSaml\SymfonyBridgeBundle\LightSamlSymfonyBridgeBundle"?
```

The project is rebuilt cleanly in docker. Caches cleared etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to [use classmaps](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md#optimization-level-1-class-map-generation) (turn ***optimize-autoloader*** on).